# How should I tag questions about MTV's Teen Wolf?

Tags: support, tags

I'm curious how I should tag questions about the MTV series *Teen Wolf*, as there are multiple media properties with the name "Teen Wolf," including two 80s films and a 90s television series in addition to the recent MTV addition.

To avoid confusion, what would the appropriate tag be in keeping with established site norms?

Comment: There appears to be no questions about any of them; is it likely to be an issue?

Comment: Is it really Science Fiction? (I haven't watched, but since MTV is mentioned, I'm skeptical)

Comment: @MatthewRead Ha, that's why I was asking, though! I wanted to be sure any tag I added was in keeping with the current taggings scheme. :)

Answer (score 4):

[teen-wolf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teen-wolf)[tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) should be enough, maybe make it clear near the beginning and end of the question (for those of us with only enough attention span to read that much) that it's about the newer one if that part is important.

Comment: Also worth noting is that you can edit the tag wiki once you've created it to specify what series it is

Answer (score 1):

I will steal @Matthew Read's comment idea.

Due to the fact that we have almost no questions (zero as of now) with the tag about ANY of the properties, there doesn't appear to be  any need to differentiate as of yet.

If/when we have enough of them, we can easily re-tag once it makes sense ([mtv-tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtv-tv-series) being a random option)